# drag and drop of jcomponents in java in rum time

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

I can do this:
I have a JFrame with 2 `JPanel` objects. In the panel on the left, I want to put the components of Java Swing useful for the construction of an user interface. The panel on the right is empty.

On run-time, my user should to be able to copy with drag and drop drag from one panel to another the selected component. But the copied component on the right panel, can be moved or deleted.

I have created the panel, but I don't know if is better inserire the component as image, label or true component.. and how to make this possible..

This is my panel for the customization.. I have to insert the component in the `JTabbedPane` in the `PanelSx`..

```
public class Customize extends JFrame {

    private JPanel panelSx, panelCx, panelMobile;
    private JButton buttonSave;
    private TabbedPaneComponents tpc;

    public Customize(){
    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setResizable(true);
    setTitle("Design Preview");
    setSize(800, 650);
    setLocation(250,50);

    panelSx = new JPanel();
    panelSx.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
    panelSx.setOpaque(true);
    panelSx.setBackground(Color.RED.darker());

    panelCx = new JPanel();
    panelCx.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
    panelCx.setOpaque(true);
    panelCx.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

    // display panel
    panelMobile = new JPanel();
    panelMobile.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,500));
    panelMobile.setOpaque(true);
    panelMobile.setBackground(Color.PINK.darker());
    panelMobile.setFocusable(false);

    buttonSave = new JButton("Save");

    panelCx.add(panelMobile);

    c.add(panelSx, BorderLayout.WEST);
    c.add(panelCx, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    tpc = new TabbedPaneComponents();
    panelSx.add(tpc);
}


}


public class TabbedPaneComponents extends JTabbedPane{

    private JPanel panel1,panel2,panel3;

    public TabbedPaneComponents(){

    panel1 = new JPanel(); 
    panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,300));
    addTab("Form Widgets", panel1); 

    panel1 = new JPanel(); 
    panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,300));
    addTab("Text Field", panel2); 

    panel1 = new JPanel(); 
    panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,300));
    addTab("Other", panel3); 

    }
}
```

Comment: Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.  BTW - *"but I don't know if is better inserire the"*  What do you mean by 'inserire'?  It is not a word I understand.

Answer (score -1):

I would have to suggest using a `JToolBar` because of it's built in drag'n'drop features. I would put the component inside of the toolbar.

Comment: Showing some sample code would help make this a better answer